# Can a set of .c files be compiled into a library for Xamarin import?

Tags: ios, import, xamarin, flac

I am writing a mono touch application on Xamarin platform.

The Google Speech to Text API is implemented for iOS in [this library](https://github.com/H2CO3/libsprec).

For me, a .net/Xamarin dev(noob) this is just a set of .c files and the list of dependencies in README (those dependencies are .deb files).

How should I compile this in XCode into a Xamarin importable format? An answer in the form of:

1. Create new project in XCode.
2. Add .c files
3. Add .deb files

would be best. I just need a high level guidance.

Comment: Why do you want to use a C library, when you can do it directly in C#, http://conceptdev.blogspot.hk/2013/09/android-texttospeech-api-with-xamarin.html

Comment: @LexLi, the topic under question is Speech-to-Text, not visa-versa.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/#3.accessing-c-methods-from-c